# Compare two sets of data, looking both ways, highlighting amount differences

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I want to know how to compare two sets of data looking both ways to identify any coding and/or amount discrepancies between the two:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvEPJ.png)
[image]

I can use basic VLOOKUPs in a long winded fashion but is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 1):

Please select Column B and ColumnE then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$B1<>$E1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, OK, OK.

Comment: This is a simple answer as it doesn't require VBA. Note that using Excel's normal processing, this would be impossible to do in both directions as each cell looks at the other and then back again. However conditional formatting is allowed to have a 'circular reference' like this, because it can't impact the actual values of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

**Without VBA**: select both ranges, then `Goto` (ctrl+G), `Special`, `Row differences`.
**Same in VBA**: use `Selection.RowDifferences(ActiveCell).Select` or use the recorder as a helper.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions above.  I didn't realise there was an option to identify differences on the "go to" function